# Migrated SharePoint 2010 Workflows fail to open in SP Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, migrate

We migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. We migrated over our SharePoint 2010 workflows - all of them are running fine. However, when we try and open them in SharePoint Designer 2013 it fails. There really isn't any error message. I looked in both the SharePoint log files and the Windows event mgr, but nothing I can see in them points to anything. I thought it might be permissions so I tried to access them as the farm account with the same results.

- Only happens with the migrated workflows
- New workflows that are created are accessible

Thanks for any help on this.

R Zoolander

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if you have SharePoint Designer 2013 SP1 installed. Open Designer and click Account and then About SharePoint Designer. The version will be the first line. If SP1 is installed, the version will be 15.0.4569.1506 or higher. If it is lower, you may consider installing SP1.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will check on this today and update on results.